# Updating kernel on stable box

Tags: upgrade

Is it a bad idea to upgrade the linux kernel when my linux box is stable? I was running an ugrade and I noticed that I got the message

```
The following packages have been kept back: linux-generic-pae linux-headers-generic linux-headers-generic-pae linux-image-generic-pae
```

I am running Ubuntu 12.04.1 and have no problems at all. Should I run

```
sudo apt-get dist-upgrade
```

and risk running into any problems, or should I just run

```
sudo apt-get upgrade
```

and leave the packages held back back?

I just want to know what common practise in this situation is.Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

usually if it ain't broke, don't fix it. so just leave it alone if things are working as you want them to, when it comes to any upgrade, unless you have security and other corporate policy/compliance requirements to do otherwise.